# Having issue with ejs object with node js and chart js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, ejs

EDIT:

In my ejs file:

```
const labelss = ['<%=data.hora_fecha%>']
const datos = ['<%=data.valor_tmp%>']
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labelss,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: datos,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
               
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In my js file:

```js
conexion.query('SELECT Temperatura,Fecha_Hora FROM informacion ORDER BY Num_muestras desc LIMIT 1', (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('No se ha podido realizar consulta a la base de datos por el error :' + error);
  } else {
    const var1 = results[0].Temperatura
    const var2 = results[0].Fecha_Hora
    valor_tmp.push(var1)
    hora_fecha.push(var2)

    res.render('historico', {
      data: {
        valor_tmp,
        hora_fecha
      }
    })
  }
})
```

I can see the first value, but when i refresh the page, should be displayed the same "item", but it doesnt, all disapear and the grafic goes out

Comment: remove the single quotes, your also stringifying the number but not the array

Comment: If i remove simple quotes i got an error (var test2 = <%= JSON.stringify(y) %>)?

Comment: whats the error?, dose `x` really equal a string `[4]` or is it an array notation, its abit unclear

Comment: x = [ 50, 35 ], y = [ '2021-08-15 13:10:06', '2021-08-15 13:10:06' ]

Comment: yeah so what error did you get when using `var test2 = <%= JSON.stringify(y) %>`? Look at the rendered source, if it looks like `var test2 = ["2021-12-03 15:00:11"]` its working, the error is something else, if it looks like `var test2 = '["2021-12-03 15:00:11"]'` is a string not a javascript literal array because of the single quotes

Comment: I dont know what is happening right now

Comment: btw, you really should make an endpoint for the chart data and use ajax to grab it, passing things like this onto the dom is bad practice

Comment: Yes i could use ajax, but about refreshing is not a problem, because for the purpose i only need to refresh two times per hour.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but now im getting rare values, i mean:

Comment: Its probably because im not using correct formats, i am stucked at all :(

Comment: use `const labelss = <%=JSON.stringify(data.hora_fecha)%>`

Comment: Still not working